# Finite dimensional function space?

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, vectors

I try to understand why we call a vector space infinite dimensional vector space. As far as I know, the set of polynomials  is an infinite dimensional vector space. I guess it is indeed, because it has infinitely many basis vectors: $$1,x,x^2,x^3,...$$  I hope this is what infinite dimensional vector space mean.

I wonder if there is any finite dimensional function space? For instance the set of functions, which functions have the form of $$ax+b$$ is a good example for finite dimensional function space? Here the basis vectors could be the identity function: $x$ and an arbitrary $C\in\mathbb R$ constant. Am I right? Sorry if its not the first question in the topic, I just want to understand it with my own examples.

Comment: You are right! Taking the vector space of polynomials of degree less then or equal to k, you will get a vector space that have dimension k+1. Your example is the case k  = 1.

Comment: In a more general way you can take any finite collection of functions $f_i:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (not necessarily polynomials) and the span of the $f_i$'s is giving you a real vector space of finite dimension. Typically, the solution space of linear homogeneous ODE's is a vector space of finite dimension...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function space is a set $F$ of functions from a set $A$ into a set $B$. If the set $B$ is also a real vector space, then it makes sense to ask whether or not $F$ is a real vector space, with respect to the usual operations of sum and product by a scalar.

In particular, yes, the set of functions from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$ which are of the form $x\mapsto ax+b$ *is* a function space. Actually, it is a $2$-dimensional vectors space, by the reason that you mentioned (excpet that you should add that $C$ cannot be $0$).

And the set of all polynomial functions from $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb R$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space, since it has an infinite basis: $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots\}$.